# Java - copy constructor - java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, arrays, constructor

i'm trying to copy an object with a copy constructor, but it outputs an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Polynomial.<init>(Polynomial.java:30)
at Polynomial.showDerivative(Polynomial.java:59)
at Program.main(Program.java:9)
```

This is my copy constructor:

```
public Polynomial(Polynomial poly)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        a[i] = poly.a[i];
    for(int i = 0; i < b.length; i++)
        b[i] = poly.b[i];
}
```

And this is how I instantiate the object:

```
Polynomial pol = new Polynomial(this);
```

What do I do?

Thanks.

Comment: Post your `Polynomial` class, not just the constructor. We need to know, what is `a`?

Comment: Check the length of `poly.a` and `poly.b` and don't use it blindly in these lines `a[i] = poly.a[i];` and `b[i] = poly.b[i];`.

Comment: Why do i need to check them? They're supposed to be exactly the same.

Comment: `Polynomial.java:30` - You need to post the code for `Polynomial` class.

Comment: @shohamh: You haven't showed us where you are initializing the arrays, or even what type they are. How do we know they are the same length and initialized properly? You haven't even told us which line is line 30, the one causing the exception.

Comment: Thanks, managed it because of Srinivas.

Comment: My vote would be for `a=poly.a.clone(); b=poly.b.clone();`.

Comment: @SoftwareMonkey.. And my downvote would be for your suggestion. I prefer copy constructor than using clone method. Also read `Effective Java`. It has a chapter on this topic, which says avoid `clone` method.

Comment: @Rohit: I mean for cloning the arrays within the copy constructor.

Comment: @RohitJain: If the arrays contain primitives, wrappers, or some other immutable objects, then cloning seems like a good idea. If you want to explain why it's a bad idea, i'd be interested to hear that, but i need more than "I prefer" or an appeal to authority.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be better with using [`System.arraycopy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) for creating a copy of your array.

Further, change your copy-constructor to: -

```
public Polynomial(Polynomial poly)
{
    int aLen = poly.a.length;
    int bLen = poly.b.length;

    // Initialize arrays for this object
    a = new int[aLen];  // Assuming `a` and `b` are integer arrays
    b = new int[bLen];  // Change accordingly.

    // A better way to create copy of arrays would be to use `System.arraycopy
    System.arraycopy( poly.a, 0, a, 0, aLen);
    System.arraycopy( poly.b, 0, b, 0, bLen);


    /*** You can avoid using below loops ***/

    // Iterate till the `aLen` of `poly` object passed 
    // and add elements to `a` array of this object
    /*for(int i = 0; i < aLen; i++)
        a[i] = poly.a[i];

    // Iterate till the `bLen` of `poly` object passed 
    // and add elements to `b` array of this object
    for(int i = 0; i < bLen; i++)
        b[i] = poly.b[i]; */
}
```

Your `for` loop should run till the length of `poly.a` and `poly.b` and not `a` and `b`, because they are not yet initialized, and hence `NPE`.

Comment: Yea, that's what I did, I'll tick it in 5 minutes when it'll let me.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `Polynomial` class looks like this:

```
public class Polynomial {

    private int[] a;
    private int[] b;

    public Polynomial(int length) {
        a = new int[length];
        b = new int[length];
    }

    public Polynomial(Polynomial poly)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
            a[i] = poly.a[i];
        for(int i = 0; i < b.length; i++)
            b[i] = poly.b[i];
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Polynomial p = new Polynomial(2);
        Polynomial q = new Polynomial(p);
    }

}
```

Then the problem is that the instance variables `a` and `b` aren’t
initialized in the copy constructor. Each constructor is independent, and
if you want to perform actions from one inside another, you have to do it
explicitly by calling a common initialization function, e.g.

```
public class Polynomial {

    private int[] a;
    private int[] b;

    private void init(int length) {
        a = new int[length];
        b = new int[length];
    }

    public Polynomial(int length) {
        init(length);
    }

    public Polynomial(Polynomial poly)
    {
        init(poly.a.length);
        for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
            a[i] = poly.a[i];
        for(int i = 0; i < b.length; i++)
            b[i] = poly.b[i];
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Polynomial p = new Polynomial(2);
        Polynomial q = new Polynomial(p);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use:

```
public Polynomial(Polynomial poly) {
    a=poly.a.clone(); 
    b=poly.b.clone();
    }
```

which will create and copy the arrays in one step each.